# Automatically create a post for each user using wp_insert_post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, dynamically-generated, user-registration

I'm looking to automatically create a post in a custom post type ( `jt_cpt_team` ) for each user with at least Author credentials.

Primarily, it needs to do this for each new user created by an admin. If there is an easy way to generate a post for each of the exiting authors (~30) then that's great, but I don't mind doing these by hand if needs be.

I'm guessing this is more-or-less what I need — struggling to get it to work though…

```
class team_functions {

  public function __construct() {

    add_action('user_register', array($this, 'create_authors_page'));

  }

  public function create_authors_page($user_id) {

    $the_user      = get_userdata($user_id);
    $new_user_name = $the_user->user_login;
    $my_post       = array();
    $my_post['post_title']   = $new_user_name;
    $my_post['post_type']    = 'jt_cpt_team';
    $my_post['post_content'] = '';
    $my_post['post_status']  = 'publish';
    $my_post['post_theme']   = 'user-profile';

    wp_insert_post( $my_post );

  }

}
```

Moreover, if there's a way to add the author's email as a `custom_field` that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance for all your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public function create_authors_page( $user_id ) {

    $the_user      = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $new_user_name = $the_user->user_login;
    $PostSlug      = $user_id;
    $PostGuid      = home_url() . "/" . $PostSlug;

    $my_post = array( 'post_title'   => $new_user_name,
                      'post_type'    => 'jt_cpt_team',
                      'post_content' => '',
                      'post_status'  => 'publish',
                      'post_theme'   => 'user-profile',
                      'guid'         => $PostGuid );

    $NewPostID = wp_insert_post( $my_post ); // Second parameter defaults to FALSE to return 0 instead of wp_error.

     // To answer your comment, adding these lines of code before the return should do it (Have not tested it though):
     $Key   = $new_user_name; // Name of the user is the custom field KEY
     $Value = $user_id; // User ID is the custom field VALUE
     update_post_meta( $NewPostID, $Key, $Value );

     return $NewPostID;
     }
```

Comment: One other thing - I would like to populate a `custom_field` with the Authors ID - is this possible within this function? Thanks.

Comment: @richerimage Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you Felipe - this is very close to working for me!

Comment: Only thing being is is need a consistent custom_field key - rather than a specific one to each post.

Comment: So rather than being...

`$Key   = $new_user_name;`

it needs to be `$Key   = 'jt_user_id';`

This however does not work - any further ideas? 

(Your assistance here is very much appreciated :)

Comment: all sorted now :)

I had the variable `$key` in lowercase. The variable in `update_post_meta( $NewPostID, $Key, $Value );` had a capitalized 'K'!

Thank you for all your help - this code is now working perfectly.