# Automatically create a post for each user on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, dynamically-generated, user-registration

I'm trying to automatically create a custom post (`users`) upon registering a new user to my site. I'm just barely familar with php, but I've been working from another question from stackoverflow: [Automatically create a post for each user using wp_insert_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678703/automatically-create-a-post-for-each-user-using-wp-insert-post)

I would ideally love to create a page that carries over custom fields upon registering or updating user information. I've used ACF to create custom fields that are associated with; users (listed in the code as lowercase variables), and the to-be-created custom posts (listed in the code as uppercase variables).

```
function create_authors_page( $user_id ) {

$the_user           = get_userdata( $user_id );
$new_user_name      = $the_user->user_login;
$PostSlug           = $user_id;
$PostGuid           = home_url() . "/" . $PostSlug;
$member_bio         = get_field('member_bio');
$contact_info       = get_field('contact_info');
$member_affiliation = get_field('member_affiliation');

$my_post = array( 'post_title'   => $new_user_name,
                  'post_type'    => 'users',
                  'post_content' => '',
                  'post_status'  => 'publish',
                  'post_theme'   => 'user-profile',
                  'guid'         => $PostGuid );

$NewPostID = wp_insert_post( $my_post ); 
 $Member_Bio            = $member_bio; 
 $Contact_Info          = $contact_info; 
 $Member_Affiliation    = $member_affiliation;
 update_post_meta( $NewPostID, $Member_Bio, $Contact_Info, $Member_Affiliation );

 return $NewPostID;
 }
```

add_action('publish_members', 'create_authors_page');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hook is incorrect, use [user_register](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/) action hook which fires after a user has registered and passes `$user_id` as a variable:

```
add_action('user_register', 'create_authors_page');
function create_authors_page( $user_id ) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

You can also use [profile_update](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/profile_update/) hook that trigger each time user update profile.

Comment: Changing the hook resulted in pages being created with the appropriate post type and name, but none of the custom fields are being transferred.  Looking on ACF, both WP users and the "users" custom post type have appropriate custom fields, but the script is not assigning the values to the "users" fields.